# Is generic Cialis (Tadalafil) equivalent to Cialis?

Tags: urology, erectile-dysfunction

I have been suffering Erectile Disfunction and i discussed it with a urologist. The urologist described me Cialis 20 mg (suggested 10 mg first). The problem is that the price is very high in the USA. I told this to the urologist, who suggested I get it from a Canadian pharmacy.

I'm from Bangladesh, where some reputed drug companies make similar medicine, Tadalafil. Is it okay to take that one instead since it is much less expensive?

Answer (score 2):

Tadafil is the generic name for Cialis

Drugs.com provide an [international list of brand names which includes Cialis](https://www.drugs.com/international/tadalafil.html) whilst MedIndia provides a [list which doesn't contain Cialis](http://www.medindia.net/drug-price/tadalafil.htm) along with their prices in in Indian Rupees (₹).

Going for Cialis is the same as going for any other brand name. They all contain the active drug (Tadafil).

Answer (score 1):

*Tadalafil is the generic form of Cialis, and it is exactly the same in its effects.*

In the United States, the Lily company holds a patent that prevents the generic form being sold until September 27, 2018.  However, the generic form is already available legally in most parts fo the world.

I would recommend great caution when buying tadalafil.  While tadalafil is safe and effective, ED medications are among the most commonly faked.  Be sure you buy from an established, reputable pharmacy, and avoid buying online.

Answer (score -1):

[Tadalafil](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tadalafil) is second generation medicine after Viagra. Normally [doctors prescribe generic name of a medicine](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/303039.php). Request him to prescribe generic name, then choose the company.

Comment: Hi, this is correct except that I'm not sure what "choose the company" means?  Yes Tadalafil = the generic (non-brand-name) version of Cialis.  Said another way, Cialis is a fancy brand name for tadalafil since they released it. It is the same medication.

Comment: Any references?

Comment: Wikipedia article added as reference.

Comment: this doesn't address whether the generic is interchangeable with the brand name at all. The OP already knows that Tadalafil is the generic and Cialis is the brand name. That's not the question. Nor is "how can I get my doctor to prescribe me a generic" the question, though your answer of "request him to" isn't exactly groundbreaking if that was the question.

Comment: I updated it with a reference, please check it.